# VimeoUploadException [ 0 ]: Unable to get an upload ticket

Tags: php, vimeo-api

Using the [Vimeo PHP API](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php) with a Pro Vimeo account.

I have a PHP form with file input, user uploads a file via the form and I want it to upload to our Vimeo account. Looking at the docs I have the following:

```
// via https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/XXXXXX#authentication
// access_token has been generated with "public private purchased create edit delete interact upload" scope
$lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret'], $config['access_token']);

// send to the API library
$uri = $lib->upload($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

// get the info about it so we can find the link
$video_data = $lib->request($uri);

// pull the link out of successful data responses.
$link = '';
if($video_data['status'] == 200)
{
    $link = $video_data['body']['link'];
}
```

It throws `Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoUploadException [ 0 ]: Unable to get an upload ticket.` when calling `$this->perform_upload($file_path, $ticket);`.

```
private function perform_upload($file_path, $ticket)
{
    if ($ticket['status'] != 201) {
        throw new VimeoUploadException('Unable to get an upload ticket.');
    }
```

The $ticket response is empty:

`Array ( [body] => [status] => 0 [headers] => Array ( ) )`

and `$curl_info` value:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.094
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.094
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [primary_port] => xxx
    [local_ip] => xxxxxxxxx
    [local_port] => xxxxxxx
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the $ticket passed into perform_upload? That should include a more clear error message.

Comment: @Dashron updated question with contents of $ticket which is empty. Do you think it could be a local cURL issue?

Comment: Definitely. Check out our SSL troubleshooting comments here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#troubleshooting

Comment: Also, do other requests work?

Comment: @Dashron working on dev box so it must be cURL. I didn't see the Troubleshooting section before, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send request for upload access in your app details page and wait for accept from Vimeo.